# Angular 2 addEventListener inside directive

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive

I'm writing Angular 2 application and inside it I have dropdown menu written on Bootstrap

```
<li class="dropdown" dropdown>
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       User <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="download">
       <li><a routerLink="/user/profile">My Profile</a></li>
       <li><a (click)="logout()">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

All what I want is to write down a small directive for toggling menu. End here is it:

```
@Directive({
    selector: "[dropdown]"
})
export class DropdownDirective implements OnInit {

    private isOpen = false;
    private defaultClassName: string;

    @HostListener('click') toggle() {            

    let that = this;

    if (!this.isOpen) {

        this.elRef.nativeElement.className = this.defaultClassName + " open";

        document.addEventListener("click", () => {             
            that.elRef.nativeElement.className = that.defaultClassName;
            that.isOpen = false;
            document.removeEventListener("click");
        });

        this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
    }


    }

    constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {

    }    

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.defaultClassName = this.elRef.nativeElement.className;
    }

}
```

Looks good. But doesn't work. After short debug I found that event listener, which was added to the document, fires just after it has been assigned.

```
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
                    that.elRef.nativeElement.className = that.defaultClassName;
                    that.isOpen = false;
                    document.removeEventListener("click");
});
```

As a fact menu closing just after it has been opened. How to fix it and why this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved this same situation with a `@HostListener()`. On the component holding the dropdown:

```js
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
private clickAnywhere(event: MouseEvent): void {
 if (this.IsSelected && !this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target)) {
  this.IsSelected = false;
 }
}
```

`this.IsSelected` is the binding property I use to show the dropdown.
The condition in the `if()` is checking whether the user has clicked on the menu or the document body in general.

Make sure to inject elementRef into the constructor so you can access the rendered HTML to check if that is what was clicked:
`public constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) { }`

You can find out more about HostListener [here](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#respond-to-user-initiated-events).